# How to call a memberfunction by pointer

Tags: state-machine

currently I try to implement a small State-Action-Matrix.
I got a table which holds information about my current state from which the program is to transition to a new follow state.

In the progress of transitioning from one state to another state, the program is supposed to call a specific memberfunction.

Example of the Transitiontable:

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    int state;
    int followState;
    /* POINTER TO MEMBERFUNCTION */
}STATE_TRANSITION;


STATE_TRANSITION stateTransition[] =
{
    { state1, state2, /* ... */ },
    /* ... */
};
```

The Memeberfunctions which are to be called from this Table are located in a class.

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    int foo(int);
};
```

My Problem now ist, how do I call for an example the Memeberfunction 'foo' and pass arguments to it?

Any help would be appiciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typedefinitions to implement a Lookuptable, directing from one current-state to a follow-state. The first typedef defines a Memberfunction-Pointer. Said pointer then is implemented in a struct to symbolize the Lookuptable.

```
typedef bool(MP_Commands::*Member)();

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t currState;      // Current State
    uint8_t followState;    // Follow State
    Member  func;           // Transition Function
}STATE_TRANSITION;
```

I then integretaed said lookup-table as private-attribute of my class so the pointers may access private-memberfunctions.

```
class A
{
private:
    STATE_TRANSITION stateTransitions[15];
    /*...*/
};
```

The Lookup-Table itself is implemented as follows:

```
static const STATE_TRANSITION _stateTransitions[] =
{ 
    { state1, state2, &A::memberFun },
    /*...*/
};

memcpy(stateTransitions, _stateTransitions,
    LENGTH(stateTransitions) * sizeof(stateTransitions[0]));
```

---EDIT---
Sorry, I forgot to mention how to make use of such an implementation:

```
(*this.*stateTransitions[i].transition)();
```

Example:

```
if((*this.*stateTransitions[i].transition)())
{ /* Do ... */ }
```